# Manually accessing an ArrayLists with a ArrayList

Tags: java, arraylist, adjacency-list

I'm working with Depth First Search program and I'm trying to create a Adjacency List Representation.
I read through some articles stating that an creating ArrayLists within an ArrayList would be the best representation.

Let's say I initialized the arraylist within a arraylist like so:

```
List<List<Integer>> adjList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

My question is how would you input data into the arraylist MANUALLY. I'm trying to understand the concept of arraylist with an arraylist before I begin my programming. If someone could possibly insert data into this arraylist so I could see the proper way of setting up.

Any additional input on anything I might need or take in consideration is recommended.

BTW: This is not a homework assignment just using personal time looking through my old textbooks.

Comment: Just to make you aware of an alternative representation. The Google Collections API (Guava - http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com/svn-history/r14/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/Multimap.html) provides a `Multimap` - an alternative data structure you could use as `Multimap<Integer,Integer>`.

Comment: @StefanWinkler thanks, I was unaware of this. I'll definitely look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say you want to add 2 lists, one with 1 and 2 and the other with 10 and 20. A very manual way of adding could be:

```
List<List<Integer>> adjList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

adjList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>()); // initialise new ArrayList<Integer>
adjList.get(0).add(1); // add value one by one
adjList.get(0).add(2);

adjList.add(new ArrayList<Integer>());
adjList.get(1).add(10);
adjList.get(1).add(20);
```

You could also write it this way:

```
List<List<Integer>> adjList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();

ArrayList<Integer> a1 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // initialise new ArrayList<Integer>
a1.add(1); // add value one by one
a1.add(2);
adjList.add(a1);

ArrayList<Integer> a2 = new ArrayList<Integer>(); // initialise new ArrayList<Integer>
a2.add(10); // add value one by one
a2.add(20);
adjList.add(a2);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `adjList` can contain the elements of the type `List<Integer>`, so create one and add using `add(E element)` function as we would for adding an element:

```
ArrayList<Integer>aList = new ArrayList<>();
adjList.add(aList);
```

Then to add an element to the element(which has the type `List<Integer>`) of `adjList`: you can try getting it using `get(index)` and add your element:

```
adjList.get(0).add(10);
adjList.get(0).add(22);
```

Try adding a second list and get it's index using `get(1)` and add the `Integer` element to the list at index `1` as the above example suggest. There are other known function too. Please check the [**`class ArrayList<E> documentation`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) page.

Answer (score 0):

Well, a list of a list of Integer objects could be done as such:

```
List<List<Integer>> adjList = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
List<Integer> li = new ArrayList<Integer>();

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    li.add(i);
}

adjList.add(li);
```

Add to each sublist, and then add the sublist.

Answer (score 0):

This will help

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        //creating a new ArrayList of List of Integers
        ArrayList<List<Integer>> integerListContainer = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        //Creating the first child arraylist of Integers
        ArrayList<Integer> firstChildintegerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        //filling the values 1,2,3 in it
        firstChildintegerList.add(1);
        firstChildintegerList.add(2);
        firstChildintegerList.add(3);
        //adding this integer list to the parent list
        integerListContainer.add(firstChildintegerList);
         //Creating the second child arraylist of Integers
        ArrayList<Integer> secondChildintegerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        //filling the values 10,20,30 in it
        secondChildintegerList.add(10);
        secondChildintegerList.add(20);
        secondChildintegerList.add(30);
        //adding this integer list to the parent list
        integerListContainer.add(secondChildintegerList);
        System.out.println("Printing the parent list to see what it has: ");
        System.out.println(integerListContainer.toString());
    }
```

Hope it clearly explains what happens